# python change the loop variable in function body

Tags: python

I found a behaviour in Python which is slightly counter-intuitive (or rather not what I am used to!). So, I have some code as follows:

```
for c in range(10):
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

This prints

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Even doing something like:

```
c = 0
for c in range(10):
   ...
```

Does not change the output? I guess the scoping rules are different than C++. My question is if someone needs to change the loop index within the function body, how could one do it?

Comment: `c` is set from the `range` object at the top of each loop. If you don't want that, use another kind of loop, like a `while` loop, and increment the variable manually. It might make your code clearer anyway.

Comment: Could you elaborate what you were actually expecting?

Comment: @nautical Was expecting 1, 3, 5, 7, 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `for` statement is a form of assignment; after the body is executed, a new value is assigned to `c`, overwriting any changes you may have made in the body. That is, the loop

```
for c in range(10):
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

is equivalent to

```
itr = iter(range(10))
while True:
    try:
        c = next(itr)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    c += 1
    print(c)
```

If you want to be able to modify `c`, you need to use a `while` loop:

```
c = 0
while c < 10:
    ...  # Arbitrary code, including additional modifications of c
    c += 1  # Unconditionally increase c to guarantee the loop eventually ends
```

Answer (score 1):

You **can't change the loop index** in Python using a for loop. It will **reset back** every loop as chepner explained in his answer.

You could, however, write it using a step (3rd variable of range). To insert step you need to pass start and end too.

```
for c in range(1,10,2): # start, end (not included), step
    print(c)

# 1,3,5,7,9

for c in range(9,0,-2): 
    print(c)

# 9,7,5,3,1
```